# Vuetify datatable not show custom cells with v-slot

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-data-table

I have an asp `.net` web forms app with `Vue 2.7.14` and `Vuetify 2.6.13`.

I have a table and I want to implement `v-slot:item.fieldName` to style certain cells but it doesn't work.

```
<v-data-table :footer-props="{ 'items-per-page-options': [10, 50, 100, 500, 1000] }" :items-per-page="10" :headers="headers" :items="supplierList" :loading="loadingGrid" :loading-text="$t('gral_loading')" :options.sync="options" :server-items-length="totalItems">
          <template v-slot:item.businessName="{item}">
            Hola
          </template>
</v-data-table
headers: [
        { text: this.$t('supplier_code'), value: 'code' },
        { text: this.$t('supplier_businessName'), value: 'businessName' },
        { text: this.$t('supplier_alias'), value: 'alias' },
        { text: this.$t('supplier_isDirect'), value: 'isDirect' },
        { text: this.$t('supplier_isAppendFile'), value: 'isAppendFile' },
        { text: this.$t('supplier_isSendEDINotification'), value: 'isSendEDINotification' },
        { text: this.$t('supplier_cat_PlantId'), value: 'plantName' },
        { text: this.$t('supplier_cat_AnalystId'), value: 'analystProcess' },
        { text: this.$t('supplier_cat_supplierTypeId'), value: 'supplierTypeName' },
        { text: this.$t('supplier_isActive'), value: 'isActive' },
        {
          text: this.$t('gral_acciones'),
          value: 'action',
          sortable: false
        },
      ],
```

This is the array data items **:**

```
supplierList: [{
    "supplierTypeId": 1,
    "name": "Transportista",
    "description": "Transportista",
    "isScrap": false,
    "isSystem": false,
    "isActive": true,
    "isDelete": false,
    "creationDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "lastUpdate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "createdBy": 1,
    "lastUpdateBy": 0,
    "systemId": null,
    "sessionData": null,
    "item": null,
    "page": null,
    "size": null,
    "sortBy": null,
    "ascending": null,
    "alertNotification": null
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

After spending some time and play around with the `v-data-table` demo, I found that as long as the headers value is in lowercase the issue doesn't appear.

Working Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      headers: [{ text: 'Code', value: 'code' },
                { text: 'Business Name', value: 'businessname' },
                { text: 'Alias', value: 'alias' },
                { text: 'Is Direct', value: 'isDirect' },
                { text: 'Is Append File', value: 'isAppendFile' },
                { text: 'Notification', value: 'isSendEDINotification' },
                { text: 'Plant Name', value: 'plantName' },
                { text: 'Analyst Process', value: 'analystProcess' },
                { text: 'Supplier Type Name', value: 'supplierTypeName' },
                { text: 'Is Active', value: 'isActive' },
                { text: 'Action', value: 'action' }],
      supplierList: [{
        "supplierTypeId": 1,
        "name": "Transportista",
        "description": "Transportista",
        "isScrap": false,
        "isSystem": false,
        "isActive": true,
        "isDelete": false,
        "creationDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "lastUpdate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "createdBy": 1,
        "lastUpdateBy": 0,
        "systemId": null,
        "sessionData": null,
        "item": null,
        "page": null,
        "size": null,
        "sortBy": null,
        "ascending": null,
        "alertNotification": null
      }],
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.14/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.14/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons"/>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="supplierList"
      :items-per-page="5">
      <template v-slot:item.businessname="{item}">
          <span>Hola</span>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```